# Use of intent filter in explicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am going one activity to another using an explicit Intent and I declare it in the manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity2"
    android:label="Activity 2">

    <intent-filter
        action android:name="com.tr.ACTIVITY2" 
        category android:name=”android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It works fine but one book uses `intent-filter` for this and I am confused about when we use intent filter.

Comment: can you just write both the samples?

Comment: [you should do some google before posting new quesiton](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=Implicit+vrs+Explicit+Intents) and specially see [this one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs)

Comment: i am using explicit intent so i think there is no need to write intent filter

Comment: actually what the book says, that code is missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use an explicit intent it's like you tell Android "open Activity2".

When you use an implicit intent you tell Android: "open an activity that can do *these things*". *these things* is actually the filter that you write in the manifest for Activity2.

As an example, if you are in Activity1 and want to start Activity2:

You can have explicit:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or implicit:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addAction("myAction");
intent.addCategory("myCategory");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in this case you should have in your manifest file something like:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="myAction"/>
      <category android:name="myCategory"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```